# Best way to populate model on edit

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I don't want to set each attribute manually, just want to do something like that

```
    $inputUser = Input::all();
    $inputUser->save();
```

But, it doesn't work.

Here is my solution where I have to set null values for empty fields as well. Also, my validation is in model file.

```
    $id = Auth::id();

    $inputUser = Input::all();
    $inputUser['id'] = $id;

    $user = new User();
    $errors = array();

    // attempt validation
    if ($user->validate($inputUser))
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->id = $id;

        foreach($user->toArray() as $key => $value)
        {
            if (array_key_exists($key, $inputUser))
            {
                if (empty($inputUser[$key])) {
                    $user->{$key} = null;
                }
                else{
                    $user[$key] = $inputUser[$key];
                }
            }
        }

        if (Input::get('password') != ""){
            $user->password = Input::get('password');
        }

        $user->save();
        return 'success';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mass assignment like below

```
$inputUser = User::find($id);
$inputUser->fill(Input::all())
$inputUser->save();
```

Just make sure that you have set $fillable in the model

```
protected $fillable = ['email', 'name'];
```

Comment: I tried that, and even if I set id as fillable I get "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' ". I set $user->id = $id;

Comment: I edited my answer. If you are editing the user then just load the Eloquent Model from DB and use the ->fill function. You should not change touch the ID of and existing object.

Comment: OK, it works, I didn't try to fetch from database and then fill. Then, it seems I have to execute two queries in order to update.

Comment: I didn't see that now my password have been set to empty string, and created_at to Null. How to exclude these fields from update?

Comment: Input::except('password', 'created_at')

Answer (score 0):

First, specify which attributes are fillable in your model (for security):

```
protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email'];
```

Then you can create model from array

```
$user = new User(Input::all());
```

or update it

```
$user->fill(Input::all());
```

Comment: After save() I get SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY . I have set ID before save().

Comment: It seems that you already have something with `id = 1` in your database (and each id have to be unique). Laravel will assign id automatically for you, so you should not try to fill it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
User::where('id', $userId )->update( Input::except('_token') );
```

But, I would check this input first. If you pass something that doesn't exist in your table (a column)..it will throw an exception.